# Displaying a Title using Placeholders

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been researching around the web, trying to work out how to display a neat grid using placeholders in Python, without using any extra functions; and nothing helpful has been found.

I want to be using data from lists to print out as different rows, for example:

```
headers = ["Generation","Juveniles","Adults","Seniles"]
genZero = [0,20,30,40]
genOne = [1,30,40,50]
genTwo = [2,40,50,60]
```

And the output would be something like:

```
Generation   Juveniles    Adults       Seniles
0            20           30           40
1            30           40           50
2            40           50           60
```

Is there any simple way to do this using placeholders in the latest version of Python? For instance, using for loops to change values and being able to display all of the values in one of lists on one line, equally spaced.

Comment: You just wanna print the output  right?

Comment: Yes, in a clear way, like what I showed...

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.